how to use datatables.net on nuxtjs 2
How to set column width and utilise datatables.net on Nuxtjs 2. With the following, it does not work.
columnDefs: [
    { width: '100px', targets: 0 },

I have attempted PrimeVue and all other options, but the table is completely broken. Would you kindly assist me or provide me with a lovely table similar to primevue/datatable?

Nuxt 2 is dead. Please refer to the documentation of Nuxt3 + Primevue on how to upgrade (or start fresh), then it should be straightforward. If you encounter any issues, please edit your questions and report them here. Also, "but the table is completely broken" is not good enough. Please consider a [repro].
